# How to use ros-noetic-husky?

Tags: husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently following the first tutorial of clearpath to learn ROS. The tutorial is already a bit outdated and uses Ros Kinetic. However, I installed Ros Noetic on my computer.
In section 'Drive a husky' (http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/ros/Drive%20a%20Husky.html), they asked to get some packages:

> sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-desktop

> sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-simulator

However I receive the following error when executing these:

> E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-husky-desktop

What can I do, to solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385568/how-to-use-ros-noetic-husky?/) by [Tom001](https://answers.ros.org/users/83180/tom001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no ROS Noetic package for Husky, however, you can clone noetic-devel and build from source. There are few dependencies required:

**Husky Simulator Installation ROS Noetic Tutorial**

**Dependencies**

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-lms1xx`

Reference: https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/velodyne_simulator/src/master/

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-velodyne-description`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-robot-localization`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_marker_twist_server

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-interactive-marker-twist-server`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/twist_mux

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-twist-mux`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/joy

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-joy`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-teleop-twist-joy`

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-dwa-local-planner`

**Create Husky workspace**

`$ mkdir husky_ws`

`$ cd husky_ws`

`$ mkdir src`

`$ cd src`

`$ git clone https://github.com/gmsanchez/husky.git`

`$ cd ..`

`$ catkin_make`

`$ echo 'source ~/husky_ws/devel/setup.bash'>>~/.bashrc`

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

**Launching simulation**

`$ cd`

`$ export HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION=$(rospack find husky_gazebo)/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro`

`$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch`

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-14**:
Husky simulation is now available for Noetic:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-husky-desktop
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-husky-simulator
```